# What makes a group of people able OR enable to form a community

Tags: word-usage

1. What makes a group of people able to form a community is not physical factors such as living in proximity but rather communication.
2. What makes a group of people enable to form a community is not physical factors such as living in proximity but rather communication.

Which one of the two sounds more natural, able or enable?  Could you help me clarify it?  Thank you so much always.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean "unable," rather than "enable." Is this true? If so, then which to choose depends on your context. What are you planning to say next? Are you planning to talk about how good communication helps people form communities? If so, use "able."

If you're planning to talk about how bad communication makes people fail to form communities, then use "unable." You might also want to say "lack of communication."

If you are planning to talk about both, then the positive "able" introduces your topic in a more optimistic way—although optimism doesn't have to be what you're going for.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is correct.  In this example, "able" is functioning as an adjective.  "Enable" is a verb, so you can't use it here.  However, you could reword example 2 as follows:

> What **enables** a group of people to form a community is not physical
>   factors...

I personally think that this is better than either of the examples you provided.  Your first sentence is acceptable, but "to make X able" is essentially just another way of saying "To enable X", so rewording the 2nd example as suggested above is a more concise way to get the point across.  To be clear, however, this is a stylistic preference, not a matter of grammar.